# Temporal linkage between two lists of data

Tags: dataset, spatio-temporal

I have 2 lists, representing a time series:

```
list_a = [23,43,29,45,6,12,240]
list_b = [13,23,11,35,60,52,40]
```

i.e. `list_a[0]` is value in first year....`list_a[6]` is values in 7th year.

I want to check if increase in values in `list_a` is followed by an increase or decrease in `list_b` in the *subsequent* year. Is there a statistical test that will allow me to do that? The key is looking at the direction of change rather than the magnitude of change.

Even better if I can say something about the temporal linkage between the two lists. I.e, perhaps increase in `list_a` precedes changes in `list_b` by 2 years.

Comment: Your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try correlation in R as follows:

```
> list_a = c(23,43,29,45,6,12,240)
> list_b = c(13,23,11,35,60,52,40)
> 
> a = list_a
> b = list_b
> 
> dd = data.frame(a,b)
> 
> dd$diffa = c(0,diff(a))
> dd
    a  b diffa
1  23 13     0
2  43 23    20
3  29 11   -14
4  45 35    16
5   6 60   -39
6  12 52     6
7 240 40   228
> 
> with(dd[-1,], cor.test(b, diffa))

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  b and diffa
t = -0.008, df = 4, p-value = 0.994
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.8129184  0.8101954
sample estimates:
         cor 
-0.003988337
```

Edit:

For using other methods:

```
with(dd[-1,], cor.test(b, diffa, method='spearman'))
with(dd[-1,], cor.test(b, diffa, method='kendall'))
```

A graph will clearly show how much delay is there. Such graph can be obtained with following code:

```
dd$time = rownames(dd)
mm = melt(dd[-3], id='time')
ggplot(mm, aes(x=time, y=value, color=variable, group=variable))+geom_point()+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I am looking at granger causality right now, not sure if statistically pearson's is the right metric.

Comment: Other methods of correlation can be specified as mentioned in my edit above.

Comment: A graph will be helpful to find the delay. The code for such graph has been added above.

Comment: @user308827 I was going to suggest Granger causality

Comment: thanks @ssdecontrol, do you know why that would be better than pure correlation?

Comment: They just don't measure the same thing. Granger causality is an hypothesis test on regression coefficients; (cross-)correlation is a quantity that is related to regression coefficients. The difference between them is analogous to the difference in the between plain (ie not intertemporal) correlation and an F test for coefficients in a multiple regression model.